# What does $.get(0) mean?

Tags: jquery

I saw it on the stripe code, but i haven't used it this way on a form submission.

https://gist.github.com/briancollins/6365455

What is the reason for using `.get(0)`?

```
var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
  var $form = $('#payment-form');

  if (response.error) {
    // Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    // token contains id, last4, and card type
    var token = response.id;
    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
    // and re-submit
    $form.get(0).submit();
  }
```

Comment: Check the docs: http://api.jquery.com/get/  `$form.get(0)` is the same as `$form[0]`.  It get the DOM element at position `0` out of the jQuery object.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Since there isn't a better (or really more involved) answer here ..

Answer (score 3):

As said in the comment :

> Check the docs: [api.jquery.com/get](http://api.jquery.com/get/) `$form.get(0)` is the same as `$form[0]`. It get the DOM element at position `0` out of the jQuery object. –  *[Rocket Hazmat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat)*

In this context it use used to submit the form.

You see, when you use `.submit()` on a jQuery Element, you trigger the jQuery method `.submit()` which is the same as `.trigger('submit')` [(ref. here)](https://gist.github.com/kagagnon/a13de27760ba1af883c0#file-gistfile1-js-L7554). Using `get(0).submit()` here will the submit method of `HTMLDomElement`, which is the native form submit.

Why would you use the native submit instead of the jQuery submit? Simply because the native submit doesnt trigger `.on('submit')` or other event bind on submit **before actually submitting the form**.

Answer (score 0):

It gets the first matching DOM element from the jQuery object

http://api.jquery.com/get/