# Plaid::InvalidRequestError

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, plaid

I am working on sending info from the Plaid link button using [this](https://stripe.com/docs/ach) tutorial from Stripe.

I have added the following code to the onSuccess function:

```
onSuccess: function(public_token, metadata) {
// Send the public_token and account ID to your app server.
var form = $('#payment-form');
form.append("<input type='hidden' name='plaid_public_token' value='" + public_token + "'/>");
form.append("<input type='hidden' name='plaid_account_id' value='" + metadata.account_id + "'/>");
form.get(0).submit();
}
```

I thought this function would be called when the user successfully adds their bank using the Plaid link. Essentially, this would get called when the form closes.

However, the behavior appears that it submits the form when the user opens the Plaid link, sending blank data to my controller.

How can I send this information to my server when Plaid is complete? Currently, it's saying that the variables are empty, but I think it's because I can't even use the Plaid pop-up before this error is being thrown.

```
Plaid::InvalidRequestError (
Error Type      : INVALID_REQUEST
Error Code      : INVALID_FIELD
Error Message   : public_token must be a non-empty string
Display Message : 
Request ID      : A1AXs
):
```

Comment: The issue is likely that your code is not preventing the default behaviour when you click on your button and it just submits the form. You need to explicitly disable the default behaviour in the click event.

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22696763/what-does-get0-mean and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317428/jquery-why-does-form-get0-submit-not-trigger-the-attached-submit-hand

Comment: Thanks arjun! I removed the `.get(0)` and my issue is solved!

Answer (score 0):

in regards to **"public_token must be a non-empty string"** and the link given from stripe.

when you create Plaid and give it a config it seems like possibly you're not giving it your link token as shown in example. Start by creating an object that contains all the needed props ie: onSuccess, onExits and **token**

based on what you have and what is given should look like the following:

```js
    const configs = {
        // where linkData.link_token is data returned from the call to the link api.
        token: linkData.link_token || '',
        onLoad: function() {
          // The Link module finished loading.
        },
        onSuccess: function(public_token, metadata) {
          // Send the public_token and account ID to your app server.
          var form = $('#payment-form');
          form.append("<input type='hidden' name='plaid_public_token' value='" + public_token + "'/>");
          form.append("<input type='hidden' name='plaid_account_id' value='" + metadata.account_id + "'/>");
          form.get(0).submit();
        },
        onExit: async function(err, metadata) {
          // The user exited the Link flow.
          if (err != null) {
              // The user encountered a Plaid API error
              // prior to exiting.
          }
          // metadata contains information about the institution
          // that the user selected and the most recent
          // API request IDs.
          // Storing this information can be helpful for support.
        },
      };

      var linkHandler = Plaid.create(configs);
```